# Make an option selected based on $_GET. Is this even possible?

Tags: php, javascript, html, get

I have a quick question.

Is it possible to do something like this?

The options are generated dynamically based on foreach loop. I want the loop to stop where the $_GET['t'] equals the $k and make it selected.

```
<option value="http://domain.com/<?php print $k; ?>/" <?php if ($k == $_GET['t']) print 'selected'; ?>><?php print $v; ?></option>
```

Basically is there a way to make the option selected/highlighted based on the provided $_GET[t'] value on the address bar.. I tried it and i get undefined index: t error.

am i missing something?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the undefined error because "t" is not in your `$_GET` request.

make sure you are calling the right url (i.e.: example.com/script.php?t=test)

Do make sure you are checking for the value (as others suggested) with `isset($_GET['t'])`

Comment: Oh I am stupid! i was trying to get the $_GET['t'] of parent document in the frame.. and the frame is in another page.. stupid me. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it - the xhtml is actually selected="selected"

```
<option value="http://domain.com/<?php print $k; ?>/" <?php if ($k == $_GET['t']) print 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php print $v; ?></option>
```

Comment: Thanks. But why I keep getting Notice: Undefined index: t and it won't work the way it expected to do.

Comment: This is correct, though your checkbox will be selected even if you don't use the right xhtml syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Above what adam noted, are you testing by actually passing a "t=something" on the end? This code should get rid of the error by testing to see if t was set first:

```
<option value="http://domain.com/<?php print $k; ?>/" <?php if (isset($_GET['t']) && $k == $_GET['t']) print 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php print $v; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use GET's to change form values on a page. You should use POST for that :)

This way, if anyone crawls your page, they won't have 10 times the same page with just the select box changed :)